# Maximum value for gauge being ignored in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am displaying a gauge using highcharts but when I set a maximum value for the display it is being ignored.  I have set it to 50 but it is always going to 60???

I have read the the api manual but I cannot seem to get it to force the maximum value.  There must be some magic combination of settings that are required.  I have tried posting on the highcharts forum but my messages don't seem to get through.

Here are my options that I am using:

```
            gaugeOptions: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'solidgauge'
                },
                title: null,
                pane: {
                    size: '140%',
                    center: ['50%', '75%'],
                    startAngle: -90,
                    endAngle: 90,
                    background: {
                        innerRadius: '60%',
                        outerRadius: '100%',
                        shape: 'arc'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                // the value axis
                yAxis: {
                    stops: [
                        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                        [0.9, '#DF5353']  // red
                    ],
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    minorTickInterval: null,
                    tickAmount: 0,
                    labels: {
                        y: 16,
                        style:{
                            color: '#FFF',
                            fontSize: '14px',
                        },
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 50,
                    title: null,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    solidgauge: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            y: 5,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            useHTML: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [40],
                    dataLabels: {
                        format:
                            '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                            '<span style="color:#FFF; font-size:16px">{y}</span></div>'
                        },
                    }
                ],
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Martyn

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is caused by the `tickAmount` option, which is set to `0`. If you don't want to show any elements reated with ticks, set:

```
    yAxis: {
        ...,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yuxe6r7m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount

Comment: thanks, i wanted to display the max and min axis values but not any others.

Comment: Hi @MartynW, Sure, just use the formatter function: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zucyjdwf/

Comment: Weird, i can see it works on your example but it won't work in my code???

Comment: There must be some difference ;)

Comment: No, I just copied and pasted your code into mine and it does not look the same???  It displays 0, the value is 40 (which is shown on the gauge) and there is no 50?  I really don't understand?

Comment: So the data or Highcharts version is different?